# Upgrading your cloud application when running it on a live cluster?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cloud, upgrade

I am working on a cloud based application which installed under Ubuntu as you would otherwise expected. For example, the server is installed as follow:

```
apt-get install snapserver
```

We have nearly 20 packages as part of the project now.

We do not yet have a running cluster, but are thinking that at some point we'd have many computers running with the software, some computers as frontends, and some computers as backends.

My question is: how do you usually update a live cluster? My concern is that new code may generate new entries in the database that are not compatible with the old code. If that happens and a client access a server that still runs the old version, it could end up crashing.

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

A sort of transactional deployment process would work here. Essentially what you would do is:

- spin up a second cluster
- copy current production data to a new database server (ensure you keep this DB updated with current data)
- spin up second application processes
- run system tests

  - if system tests pass, kill old cluster
  - if system tests fail, back to dev, shut down newly setup cluster

It's easier to do something like this when you have a VM container provider like VMware, AWS, Heroku, OpenStack, etc.

Comment: So what you are saying, more or less, is to create a duplicate (make sure it works) and then switch to the duplicate at once? That's an interesting concept. I hadn't thought of that! It could make things safer and it's probably not that expensive to double the VMs for 2 or 3 days... Cool.